# Javascript .find method cannot find the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a method

```
{payload.find((item) => item.dataKey === 'value')?.value || '-'}
```

and that's my payload that I pass normally as an array to the component with the method above, but it always returns the '-' sign:

```
export const mockedResponse = {
  area: 'test',
  bestValue: null,
  comments: 'test comments',
  controllerOnOffStatus: 'test',
  currentValue: 1,
  description: 'test description',
  id: 'test id',
  kind: 'test',
  payload: [payload],
};

const payload = {
  avg: 11,
  timestamp: '22:00',
  value: 11.07,
};
```

Any ideas why it cannot find the value? How should the mockedResponse look like, so the method would work?

Comment: what's `item.dataKey`?

Comment: > my payload that I pass normally as an array

Comment: okay I edited the response - basically I am looking why the payload in the method doesn't work and I don't have the documentation for the project for its API. Or the correct answer would be: how should I pass the payload so it would find the value as in the example above  where the payload is an array within the mocked object

Comment: So, `item` doesn't have `dataKey`. Therefore, `item.dataKey` will return `undefined`. And `undefined === 'value'` is `false`. I don't see a problem - works exactly as it should.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: how the mockedCall should look like so the exact payload.find method would work - that's what I'm trying to find

Answer (score -1):

You can not use a `find()` method for the objects. As your payload is an object like

```
const payload = {
  avg: 11,
  timestamp: '22:00',
  value: 11.07,
};
```

And you want to check if the `value` key exists in the payload object, and if so return that value, otherwise return '-', you can use the following

```
payload.value || '-'
```

After your editing, I can see that you have converted the payload to the array.
You didn't have the `dataKey` property in the payload. If you want to check if the `value` exists in the `item` please try the following

```
{payload.find((item) => item.value)?.value || '-'}
```